# shadow in UILabel

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

I tried subclassing UILabel with the following code.. but unable to get a look similar to [image: Label with DropShadow]

```
- (void) drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGSize myShadowOffset = CGSizeMake(4, -4);
    CGFloat myColorValues[] = {0, 0, 0, .8};

    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    CGContextSaveGState(myContext);

    CGColorSpaceRef myColorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGColorRef myColor = CGColorCreate(myColorSpace, myColorValues);
    CGContextSetShadowWithColor (myContext, myShadowOffset, 5, myColor);

    self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, 1);
    self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
    self.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor];

    [super drawTextInRect:rect];

    CGColorRelease(myColor);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(myColorSpace);

    CGContextRestoreGState(myContext);
}
```

Comment: `shadowOffset` should be ` CGSizeMake(0, -2)`.

Comment: dont forget to set the backgroundColor to `[UIColor clearColor]` else you wont have that result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
self.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0, -2.5);
self.layer.shadowRadius = 1;
self.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5;
self.layer.shadowColor = [UIColor blackColor].CGColor;
```

[image: Here is the output]

Answer (score 1):

`UILabel` class have shadow properties by default.

`levelLbl.shadowColor = [[UIColor blackColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:1];
 levelLbl.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(2, 2);`

P.S. for shadow like above image, you have to set `shadowRadius` over `layer`.

P.S.2 Don't forget to `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` , if you are not using `Xcode 6` or later.

Comment: Don't forget to ```#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>```